# phpmyadmin extension for postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql, phpmyadmin

Im trying to connect to amazon rds postgres through my phpadmin.

I would like to know what would be the extension type for postgres that I would specify for postgres.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';
```

if its mysql, I can set it up to 'mysql'.

Comment: You'd use `pgsql` but perhaps you should use [phpPgAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpPgAdmin) instead.

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin does not support PostgreSQL.